# Php laravel 5.3 passing an input value from one blade file to another blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to pass an input value from one blade file to another blade file.

I'm new to PHP Laravel, and I'm getting an error when attempting to use it.

I think my syntax is wrong here. Can somebody help?

channeling.blade:

```
<select class="form-control " name="fee" id ="fee"></select>
```

This is the link to the next page, where i want to send the value of "fee":

```
<input type="hidden" value="fee" name="fee" />
<a href="{{ url('pay ') }}">Click to Channel</a></p>
```

This is my web.php:

```
Route::post('pay', [
    'as' => 'fee',
    'uses' => 'channelController@displayForm'
]);
```

This my controller class:

```
 public function displayForm()
    {
        $input = Input::get();
        $fee = $input['fee'];
        return view('pay', ['fee' => $fee]);
    }
```

Error message:

```
Undefined variable: fee 
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara_test\resources\views\pay.blade.php)
```

pay.blade:

```
<h4>Your Channeling Fee Rs:"{{$fee}}"</h4>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Perhaps `channelController@displayForm` should be `ChannelController@displayForm`.

Comment: Undefined variable: fee (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara_test\resources\views\pay.blade.php)

Comment: Undefined variable: fee (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lara_test\resources\views\pay.blade.php)

this is my pay.blade
   <h4>Your Channeling Fee Rs:"{{$fee}}"</h4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code like this and it worked..

echanneling.blade

```
 <input type="hidden" value="fee" name="fee" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

channelController.php

```
public function about(Request $request)
    {

        $input = Input::get();
        $fee = $input['fee'];

        return view('pay')->with('fee',$fee);
    }
```

Web.php
Route::post('/pay', 'channelController@about' );

Answer (score 1):

You should use form to send `post` request, since `a href` will send `get`. So, remove the link and use form. If you use Laravel Collective, you can do this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'pay']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('fee', 'fee') !!}
{!! Form::submit() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

You can value inside a controller or a view with `request()->fee`.

Or you can do this:

```
public function displayForm(Request $request)
{
     return view('pay', ['fee' => $request->fee]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this, You mistaken `url('pay ')` with blank:

change your code:

```
<a href="{{ url('pay ') }}">Click to Channel</a></p>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ url('pay') }}">Click to Channel</a></p>
```

Further your question require more correction so I think you need to review it first.

You can review about [how to build a form with laravel 5.3](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#opening-a-form). Hope this helps you.

Comment: This will not work since `a href` will send `get` request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use form to post data and then you have to submit the form on click event

```
 <form id="form" action="{{ url('pay') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <input type="hidden" value="fee" name="fee" />
  </form>
```

On the click event of <a>

```
<a href="{{ url('/pay') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById('form').submit();">
      Logout
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **tl;dr:** I believe @AlexeyMezenin's answer is the best help, so far.

Your current issues:

- If you have decided to use `<a href="{{ url('pay') }}">Click to Channel</a>`, you should use `Route::get(...)`. Use `Route::post(...)` for requests submitted by Forms.
- There isn't an `Input` instance created. `Input::get()` needs a Form request to exist. Thus, the `$fee` an **Undefined variable** error message.
- The value of `<input type="hidden" value="fee" name="fee"/>` is **always going to be the string "fee"**. (Unless there's some magical spell casted by some JavaScript code).
- The [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#accessing-the-request) suggest that you type-hint the `Request` class when accessing HTTP requests, so that the incoming request is automatically injected into your controller method. Now you can `$request->fee`. Awesome, right?

---

The way forward:

- The [BasicTaskList](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) Laravel 5.2 tutorial kick-started my Laravel journey.